# read variables from file

Tags: shell

I'm trying to write a shell script to backup websites, I've got it to go through each directory in `vhosts` and create a new directory `vhosts/{siteurl}/private/backups/` and gzip up the site into there.

However, I also want it to read a file from `private` that will contain  database name, user and password. So I can then use these to perform a `mysqldump` to `private/backups/`.

The problem is that I've never written a shell script before so I've got no idea how to read variable data into my script, or how I should format the file to be read.

Hope that's enough information.

Comment: Would you like it to be `bash`, `python` or ...? Do you have any preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is in `name=value` format and you're running bash or sh then you can use `.` to read and execute the contents of the file.

`vars.txt`:

```
foo=123
bar=456
```

`script.sh`:

```
. ./vars.txt
echo "$foo * $bar"
```

Comment: if i put a command such as `find . -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \;` into `vars.txt` would it also be executed?

Comment: That is correct, as would `exit` which would promptly close the shell.